# Why displaying of web pages are different in google chrome and firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

In one form input type is date and in Google Chrome Calender is coming properly and in Firefox it is not displaying. Also radio buttons are working properly in Chrome and not in Firefox.
How to solve these problems?

Answer (score 0):

First I think you should re think your Ids since they look malformed and would not be very useful for targeting via css.

Second I think your HTML should look more like this

```
<label for="Permlt5Years" class="radio-label">
     Perm. < 5 years
     <input id="Permlt5Years" name="checkbox" type="radio">
</label>
```

Clicking on a label should select a radio button for you. When validating via direct input here [link](https://validator.w3.org/check) against html5 doctype it had 11 errors.